# SEO - sitemap.xml providing explicit links which are not on the page as anchors

Tags: seo, search-engine

I have a site with an input text.
User types the name of a city, hits enter and it's linked there.

my sitemap.xml looks like this:

```
<urlset>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/rome.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/london.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/newyork.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/paris.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/berlin.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/toronto.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/milan.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/edinburgh.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/nice.html</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.com/boston.html</loc></url>
...
</urlset>
```

My question is:
Will I be penalized (from a SEO point of view) because my links only appear on the sitemap.xml instead as in a list of anchors in the html page.

Note: the anchor approach was excluded because I have about 5,000 listed cities

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde why is off topic ? SEO is one of the tags I added to my question

Comment: Click on the tag and read it ;)

Comment: @JohnConde Fair enough. I see where you are coming from now. I still disagree with you because what I am asking is the use of various technique to aid web pages' ranking in search engines. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's *exactly* what isn't on-topic at this site and should be asked at Webmasters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be penalised.  Google themselves say the primary purpose of a sitemap is "a way to tell Google about pages on your site we might not otherwise discover."

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en

You are rare in that you are using the sitemap correctly to help Google find your pages.

Often SEOs just add one for the sake of it, rather than taking the time to identify and using it to fix potential crawling errors.

The only negative aspect for SEO I can think of is that page rank will not flow between your pages if there is no direct link.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be penalized. The sole purpose of sitemaps is to tell search engines where to find your content. That content may or may not be available through hyperlinks on your website.

Comment: have you got some reference to back up your view ?